# Remove/hide figure caption below knitted markdown->pandoc plot

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, pandoc

I don't know how to remove `Figure 1:` as seen bellow from the generated pdf document: 
(using rmarkdown; knitr; pandoc). I have a `.Rmd file > .md > .pdf`

I generate the pdf in R console as:

```
system(paste("pandoc -V geometry:margin=0.7in -o", path, "/file_name", ".pdf ", "file_Rmd", ".md" ,sep=""))
```

Simple example:

````
```{r}
plot(1:20)
```
````

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add `-fmarkdown-implicit_figures` to your `pandoc` call to disable the implicit figure extension which will, in turn, disable the "Figure # : xyz" labeling.

```
system(paste("pandoc -V geometry:margin=0.7in -fmarkdown-implicit_figures -o", path, "/file_name", ".pdf ", "file_Rmd", ".md" ,sep=""))
```

Comment: This solution disables captions for all images. Is it possible to disable the caption for only one specific image somehow?